# Azure VM: netsh advfirewall firewall

Tags: firewall, windows, azure

Being the idiot that I am, I ran `netsh advfirewall firewall` on our VM and managed to block all the ports.

Naturally, I am no longer able to access the VM through RDP.

Apart from getting the support guys involved, is there any other way to get RDP access?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9fb19165-ab6a-45e1-8417-ae3364a62255/remote-connectivity-removed-how-do-i-accessreset?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows  If it works, please consider turning it into an answer. I can't test right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete the existing role PRESERVING the disks.
2. Download the OS Disk attached to the VM using a tool like CloudXplorer (or Azure powershell cmdlets).
3. Attach the OS Disk (VHD) to a new VM in Hyper V and correct the firewall permissions.
4. Upload the modified VHD to your storage account using some tool (or Azure powershell cmdlets).
5. Create a new role using the same OS Disk and you should be good to go.

PS If you have just one role in your deployment, you won't be able to delete the role. In that case, shutdown the role you have in your deployment (StoppedDeallocated) and create a new (dummy) role in that same deployment. Then you will be able to follow the above steps. After step 5, you can delete the dummy role.

Answer (score 1):

If you blocked all the ports, that means you have no remote access to that machine at all. No winrm, winrs, ssh, telnet, ftp, ... Now you need physical access to the machine to allow yourself remote access.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every possible approach and even had Microsoft support involved. The bottom line is that you are pretty screwed.

Your options are:

- Download the VHD (see proteus' answer)
- Rebuild the VM

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this same issue.  The fastest possible solution would be to avoid downloading the entire source and uploading it again.

First step is to make **note** of the affected VM's **OS disk name** and the **name of your VM**.

Then **create** a recovery VM, it must be created **inside the existing cloud service**.

Once that has been completed, **delete** the firewalled VM but **RETAIN THE DISKS**!

When the VM has been deleted, about 5 minutes, you'll be able to **attach** the OS disk to the new recovery VM, log into the VM and you should see your drives.

Once you have access to your data, launch **regedit**, click **HKLM, once** and then **file** / **load hive**.

Open the registry files on the second drive, **drive:\Windows\System32\Config\SYSTEM.** .  Then name it something like **test**.

You'll see the registry keys under "**test**".  You can either **search** for the **name** of the firewall rule you've created that is damaged, or **search** the word **firewall** to locate the appropriate settings to change for your configuration.

Make the modifications required and **unload** the registry hive, **test**.

At this point you can **detach** the **secondary OS drive** and create a new VM from "**MY IMAGES**" in the gallery.

Select the **OS drive** and complete your configuration.

That should get you back up and running in under an hour.

***You will get a new IP address after completing this process.***